RAG framework not not working for many model listed "snowparkSQLException 1304 -- unknown model \snowflake-arctic"
I am referring below RAG example to do some experiment with some private data(some sample pdf).
https://quickstarts.snowflake.com/guide/asking_questions_to_your_own_documents_with_snowflake_cortex/index.html#4
however the model works for the first - 'mixtral-8x7b' not for others and getting below error
"snowparkSQLException 1304 -- unknown model \snowflake-arctic"

i used the exact code but with different pdf file(which i don't think making problem over here)
do i need to import other mode into the snowflake environment ?
Any solution

LLM Functions - Availability

If you refer to the official document in snowflake, an error named “unknown model” occurs because it is not yet available for the region.
Please refer to the official document as following link.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowflake-cortex/llm-functions
